# Angular2 getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'list' of object '#<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Im trying to componetize a html pattern that we use.  The html looks like this

```
    <input class="sidebarInputDevice" type="search"  [list]="listidentx" placeholder="Search {{label}}..." (input)="deviceSelected($event.target.value)"> {{listidentx}}
<datalist [id]="listidentx">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

The typescript code looks likes this

```
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-entry',
  templateUrl: './select-entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-entry.component.css']
})
export class SelectEntryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    //this.listidentx='working';
  } 

  @Input() 
    items:{}[] = [];

  @Input() 
    label = '';

  @Input()
    listident='custom';

    listidentx = 'bacon';


  @Output() 
    valueChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.items);
    console.log("-----");
    for (var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
      console.log(this.items[i]);
    }
    console.log("^----");
  }

  valSelected(value) {
    this.valueChange.emit(value);

  }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'list' of object '#<HTMLInputElement>'
```

Is there a solution to this or can i not make the list attribute dynamic.

If I cannot make the attribute dynamic can I make sure each component has a different id for its list.

Comment: What is this trying to do: `[list]="listidentx"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to an element attribute:

```
<input [attr.list]="listindent">
```

If `listident='custom'`, at runtime it will look like this:

```
<input list="custom">
```